# Filtering divs with buttons with JS

Tags: javascript, filter, contains

I'm trying to make a filter with JS.
By example; When someone click on cars button, the divs with NO brand cars should be hidden. But the problem is when after clicking cars button click also food, then cars and food filters are enable, so just their respective divs should be shown.
Also when any filter is enable, all data should be shown.

Thanks in advance!

```js
var category = document.getElementsByClassName('cat');
var filter_cat_cars = document.getElementById('filter_cat_cars');
var filter_cat_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('filter_cat_btn');
var filter_cat_food = document.getElementById('filter_cat_food');
var filter_cat_cities = document.getElementById('filter_cat_cities');


filter_cat_cars.addEventListener("click" , function() {
   filter_cat_cars.classList.toggle("cat_active");
   for (let i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
         if(category[i].classList.contains('cars')){
            category[i].classList.remove("cat_hide");
         } else{
            category[i].classList.toggle("cat_hide");
         }
   }
});

filter_cat_food.addEventListener("click" , function() {
   filter_cat_food.classList.toggle("cat_active");
   for (let i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
         if(category[i].classList.contains('food')){
            category[i].classList.remove("cat_hide");
         } else{
            category[i].classList.toggle("cat_hide");
         }
   }
});

filter_cat_cities.addEventListener("click" , function() {
   filter_cat_cities.classList.toggle("cat_active");
   for (let i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
         if(category[i].classList.contains('cities')){
            category[i].classList.remove("cat_hide");
         } else{
            category[i].classList.toggle("cat_hide");
         }
   }
});
```

```css
#filter_cat{
    display: flex;
}
.filter_cat_btn{
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    color:#bbb;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -ms-border-radius:2px;
    -o-border-radius:2px;
    padding: 10 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container_cat{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
}
.cat{
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
.cars{
    background-color: red;
}
.food{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.cities{
    background-color: blue;
}
.cat_hide{
    display: none;
}
#filter_cat_cars.cat_active{
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
}
#filter_cat_food.cat_active{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color:white;
}
#filter_cat_cities.cat_active{
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
 <div id="filter">
        <div id="filter_cat">
            <button class="filter_cat_btn" id="filter_cat_cars">Cars</button>
            <button class="filter_cat_btn" id="filter_cat_food">Food</button>
            <button class="filter_cat_btn" id="filter_cat_cities">Cities</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container_cat">
        <div class="cat cars">BMW</div>
        <div class="cat cities">Paris</div>
        <div class="cat cars">Toyota</div>
        <div class="cat food">Apples</div>
        <div class="cat cities">Roma</div>
        <div class="cat cars">Volvo</div>
        <div class="cat food">Tomatos</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: so you want to filter both when both clicked?

Comment: I run the code and didn't see any problems, everything works fine.

Comment: A quick fix is to 1. in your button handlers, always toggle 2. add `cat_active` to your filter buttons. This isn't how I'd solve this but will work as far as I can tell: https://jsfiddle.net/w5kdhf6o/

Comment: @NNL993 Run the snippet, then click "Cars", then "Food"

Comment: @ChrisG oh, now I see the problem...

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you very much, this is a breakthrough, but when all filters are disable, all data should be shown. And all filters should be disable when the page load. 
Sorry, I expressed myself wrong in the initial question.

Comment: I see, in that case do only step 1 (always toggle)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var category = document.getElementsByClassName('cat');
var filter_cat_cars = document.getElementById('filter_cat_cars');
var filter_cat_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('filter_cat_btn');
var filter_cat_food = document.getElementById('filter_cat_food');
var filter_cat_cities = document.getElementById('filter_cat_cities');
var activeCats = [];
function toogleVisibility(cat) {
  if(activeCats.indexOf(cat) < 0){
     activeCats.push(cat);
   } else {
     activeCats = activeCats.filter((item) => item !== cat);
   }
  for (let i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
      category[i].classList.remove("cat_hide");
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < activeCats.length; j++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
        if(category[i].classList. contains(activeCats[j])) {
           category[i].classList.add("cat_hide");
        }
      }
  }
}

filter_cat_cars.addEventListener("click" , function() {
   filter_cat_cars.classList.toggle("cat_active");
   toogleVisibility('cars');
});

filter_cat_food.addEventListener("click" , function() {
   filter_cat_food.classList.toggle("cat_active");
   toogleVisibility('food');
});

filter_cat_cities.addEventListener("click" , function() {
   filter_cat_cities.classList.toggle("cat_active");
   toogleVisibility('cities');
});
```

```css
#filter_cat{
    display: flex;
}
.filter_cat_btn{
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    color:#bbb;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -ms-border-radius:2px;
    -o-border-radius:2px;
    padding: 10 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container_cat{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
}
.cat{
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
.cars{
    background-color: red;
}
.food{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.cities{
    background-color: blue;
}
.cat_hide{
    display: none;
}
#filter_cat_cars.cat_active{
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
}
#filter_cat_food.cat_active{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color:white;
}
#filter_cat_cities.cat_active{
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
 <div id="filter">
        <div id="filter_cat">
            <button class="filter_cat_btn" id="filter_cat_cars">Cars</button>
            <button class="filter_cat_btn" id="filter_cat_food">Food</button>
            <button class="filter_cat_btn" id="filter_cat_cities">Cities</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container_cat">
        <div class="cat cars">BMW</div>
        <div class="cat cities">Paris</div>
        <div class="cat cars">Toyota</div>
        <div class="cat food">Apples</div>
        <div class="cat cities">Roma</div>
        <div class="cat cars">Volvo</div>
        <div class="cat food">Tomatos</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a solution to the problem, but I don't think that author of question actually wanted.